# how to check attribute value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me why `hasAttribute` give false result.I am trying to write a `jquery` lib  line in `javascript` but it is giving me wrong `output` .where I am doing wrong.

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/bagiyoyipu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

```
$(function(){
  console.log($('.abc').is('[data-bcid="sss"]'))

console.log(document.querySelector('.abc').hasAttribute('[data-bcid="sss"]'))
})
```

`console.log($('.abc').is('[data-bcid="sss"]'))` gives `true` which is correct .why `second` line gives wrong answer .it is giving false.can we write jquery line in javascript ?

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute) on how to use `hasAttribute`.

Comment: got it .so how I get true will I compare value using `getAtrribute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because your syntax is wrong. `hasAttribute` accepts only the ***name*** of the target attribute. It does not match on values.

jQuery's `is()` method works differently as it compares the given element to the selector string as a whole.

> So how I get true will I compare value using `getAttribute()`

To do that you need to first retrieve the attribute value, then check it:

```js
$(function() {
  let el = document.querySelector('.abc');
  let bcid = el.getAttribute('data-bcid');
  console.log(bcid == 'sss')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abc" data-bcid="sss">sss</div>
```

That being said, as this is a `data` attribute it's better practice to access it through the `dataset` collection instead of `getAttribute()`. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  let el = document.querySelector('.abc');
  let bcid = el.dataset['bcid'];
  console.log(bcid == 'sss')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="abc" data-bcid="sss">sss</div>
```

Comment: how I get true will I compare value using `getAtrribute`

Comment: if I want to change this line to javascript how I will do that `$('.abc').is('[data-bcid="sss"]')`

Comment: Given that goal I've updated the answer for you, and provided a different method to achieve what you need which follows better practice.

Comment: actually I am working `js` not `jquery` .working `vanilajs`

Comment: Your example is using a jQuery document.ready handler. In any case, the solution above is not using jQuery.